# Migrate PostgreSQL tstzrange array column to tsrange array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL tables defined as following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE event (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  time_zone text NOT NULL,
  start_date timestamptz NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE event_user (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  event_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES event(id),
  unavailabilities tstzrange[] NOT NULL
);
```

I need to migrate my SQL schema so that the fields `event.start_date` and `event_user.unavailabilities` are typed as local dates instead of dates with time zones. The time zone that must be used to convert the dates is located in the column `event.time_zone` (IANA Time Zone format).

I succeeded in converting the column `event.start_date` of type `timestamptz` to the type `timestamp` by using the following statements:

```sql
ALTER TABLE event RENAME COLUMN start_date TO start_date_old;
ALTER TABLE event ADD COLUMN start_date timestamp NULL;
UPDATE event e SET start_date = e.start_date_old AT TIME ZONE e.time_zone;
ALTER TABLE event ALTER COLUMN start_date SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE event DROP COLUMN start_date_old;
```

How should I proceed to convert the column `event_user.unavailabilities` of type `tstzrange[]` to the type `tsrange[]`?

```sql
ALTER TABLE event_user RENAME COLUMN unavailabilities TO unavailabilities_old;
ALTER TABLE event_user ADD COLUMN unavailabilities tsrange[] NULL;
UPDATE event_user eu SET unavailabilities = <???> FROM event e WHERE e.id = eu.event_id;
ALTER TABLE event_user ALTER COLUMN unavailabilities SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE event_user DROP COLUMN unavailabilities_old;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=41730ae2b1341d534a211de44dd83315)

1. The change of your first table can be achieved much easier when you are using the `USING` keyword in the `ALTER` command:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE event ALTER COLUMN start_date TYPE timestamp USING start_date AT TIME ZONE time_zone;
   ```
2. 1. You should avoid storing data in arrays. Please think about normalizing your data, which means: Keep your array elements in separate rows. This make everything much easier and more performant. You wouldn't have run into your current problem as well
   2. If you want to do so, there are two problems: First, you need to extract your array in order to convert the data separately. Second: AFAIK there is no way of casting a `tstzrange` directly into a `tsrange`. So, you need to create a new `tsrange` for every `tstzrange`:

```
       UPDATE event_user b
       SET unavailabilities = s.unavailabilities           -- 4
       FROM (
           SELECT 
               id,
               array_agg(tsrange(                          -- 3
                   lower(tsdata) AT TIME ZONE 'CET',       -- 2
                   upper(tsdata) AT TIME ZONE 'CET'
               )) as unavailabilities 
           FROM
               event_user,
               unnest(unavailabilities_old) tsdata         -- 1
           GROUP BY id
       ) s
       WHERE s.id = b.id;
```

Explanation:

1. Extract the array data
2. Retrieve the bounds of the `tstzranges` as `timestamptz` and convert them into your required time zone
3. Create a tsrange with the recently converted `timestamp` values and reaggregate the array afterwards
4. Do the update.

Comment: This works, thanks. Just had to add a cross join with the table `event` in the subquery to be able to use the appropriate time zone. The short syntax in your 1st point is also very welcomed :)